# @Mockbean call real method without using thenCallRealMethod()

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I tried to mock the external packages bean by `@MockBean` at JPA unit test and successed to mock it. However, the mocking bean calls real method even though it does not call `thenCallRealMethod()`. I knew that `@MockBean` register spring application context and always return null value when calling methods. Are there any missing points?

Here are the codes.

- **MyServiceImplTest.kt**

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestApplication::class])
@Import(MyServiceImpl::class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
internal class InventoryAdminApiServiceImplTest {
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var myTopicService: TopicV2Service<CustomMessage>

    @Suppress("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var myService: MyServiceImpl

    @Test
    fun `test foo`() = runTest {
        runBlocking {
            myService.foo(cancelRequest {
                id = 1
                message = "Canceled"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

- **MyServiceImpl**

```kotlin
@GrpcService
class MyServiceImpl @Autowired constructor(
    private val myTopicService: TopicV2Service<CustomMessage>,
) : MyServiceGrpcKt.MyServiceCoroutineImplBase() {
    override suspend fun foo(request: CancelRequest): Empty {
        ....
        runBlocking {
            myTopicService.publish(customMessage())
        }
    }
}
```

- **TopicV2Service**

```kotlin
open class TopicV2Service<M : Message>(private val topic: TopicV2<M>) {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var queuesProperties: QueuesProperties

    private val client = SnsAsyncClient.create()
    private val protobufPrinter = JsonFormat.printer()

    private val topicArn by lazy {
        client.createTopic { it.name("${queuesProperties.snsPrefix}${topic.name}") }
            .join()
            .topicArn()
    }

    suspend fun publish(message: M) {
        val wrappedMessage = WrappedMessage(topic.name, protobufPrinter.print(message)).let { Json.encodeToString(it) }
        client.publish { it.topicArn(topicArn).message(wrappedMessage) }.await()
    }
}
```

- Error message

```bash
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "miniproj.toy1.queues.TopicV2.getName()" because "this.topic" is null
    at miniproj.toy1.queues.TopicV2Service.publish(TopicV2Service.kt:29)
    at miniproj.toy1.inv_service.services.MyServiceImpl$foo$3$1$1.invokeSuspend(MyServiceImpl.kt:485)
```

Comment: You are mocking a `TopicV2Service<CustomMessage>` but your Service requires a `TopicV2Service<ShipmentMessage>`. Maybe if you change `CustomMessage` to `ShipmentMessage` as the Generics parameter it will autowire the mocked object correctly.

Comment: @yezper Oops...That's typo; I edit it. BTW, if I match the Generic parameter and use `@Mockbean`, then the mocked object autowire the origin bean, right?